# Where is this room with 7 frog coins?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

On the IGN article "[*How to Farm Frog Coins*](https://www.ign.com/wikis/super-mario-rpg-switch-remake/How_to_Farm_Frog_Coins)", there's an image of a room with yellow stone walls containing 3 item bags, 4 flowers, and 7 frog coins. The article doesn't explain what this room is.

How do I reach this golden room with 7 frog coins?

[image: room with 7 frog coins]

Comment: Wow, I instantly recognised where it was and how to reach it the instant I saw it. Now I feel like returning to my Snes and replaying it a twelfth time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint 1:

> That location is in Belome Temple.  However, when you find it, there's a golden Belome blocking the way who says he needs a key

Hint 2:

> There is an unreachable key in Monstro Town

Solution:

> Go to Monstro Town and talk to the Thwomp several times. This will cause the key to fall.  Then go back to Belome Temple, to the area where you have to hit the three tongues.  After hitting the tongues, if the (random?) note you receive says *"Sorry, I'm not accepting visitors past my bedtime"*, you'll be led to the treasure room.  If it says *"Mmm, I'm so hungry! Wish I had something to eat!"*, you'll need to try again.

Comment: Darn, I was writing an answer too. I'll leave [this video](https://youtu.be/4LjzCsDSZjY?si=symt4IiiLbBRAafJ&t=91) for reference then.